# Como pasar un fichero .txt a un array 2d

Tags: java

Me han puesto un trabajo en clase, me piden que pase un fichero que representa un tablero a un array bidimensional.

fichero, medidas 15x30 :

```
                      .          
  .        ###   ...   ###   
  ..     ######   .   #####  
         #######       ###   
          ####               
   .                         
   .                         
                ###          
     @@@       #####         
   @@@@@@@      ###     ..   
  @@@@@@@@              ..   
  @@@@@@@                    
   @@@     ..        ###     
           ..       #####    
                     ###
```

He intentado usar un arrayList pero luego se me pide que divida este mapa en 9 sectores, por eso quiero pasarlo a uno bidimensional,para así poder tratar los caracteres individualmente.

```
//declaro el FileReader
FileReader fr = null;

        try {
             //ruta es donde guardo mi fichero
            fr = new FileReader(ruta);
            //este for es para ir guardando los caracteres 1 a 1.
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                    int caracter = (char) fr.read();
                       array[i][j] = (char) caracter;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error : Fichero no encontrado");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Para mostrarlo ningún problema sale perfecto.

este es el for que he usado

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            }
   }
```

Ahora si quiero por ejemplo manipular la fila número 9 con un for :

```
 for(int i = 0; i < array[0].length;i++){
             System.out.print(array[9][i]);
         }
```

debería salir esto :

```
  @@@@@@@      ###     ..
```

Pero me sale esto por pantalla (fijese que faltan los dos .. finales de la linea):

```
  @@@@@@@      ###
```

Y ahora si cambio la linea a 10, es decir una mas a la que estaba haciendo

```
  ..   
 @@@@@@@@
```

me sale la linea partida, es decir una mezcla entre las dos(9 y 10), en definitiva no sé muy bien como hacerlo si ustedes me pueden guiar sería de mucha ayuda.
Pueden preguntar cualquier cosa, yo les daré información por si se me olvidó algo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa con tu codigo es al hacer `fr.read();` va caracter por carcater, tambien contempla el caracter 10 que es un break o espacio para la nueva linea, asi que debes contemplar este caracter de mas en tu tamaño de matriz,por esto es que ves que se hace un salto al imprimir algunas lineas, el codigo quedaria asi:

```
    char[][] array = new char[15][31];
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("doc.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = (char) fr.read();
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < array[9].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(array[9][j]);
    }
```

Si no contemplas el caracter de mas se veria algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes observar como se va formando una diagonal con el salto de linea (caracter 10), en el caso que contemplaramos ese caracter adicional se veria algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ya podemos ver como el carácter 10 efectivamente queda al final de cada linea.

Esta es una forma mas fácil de hacerlo ya que no contempla el salto de linea
Se declara el numero de filas y columnas

```
    int filas= 14;
    int columnas= 29;

    char[][] myArray = new char[filas][columnas];

    File file = new File("doc.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

Utilizo .toCharArray(); para obtener cada caracter como un arreglo y poderlo recorrer

```
    for (int fila= 0; fila< filas; fila++) {
        char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            myArray[fila][i] = chars[i];
        }
    }
```

Muestro los caracteres de la fila:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray[9].length; i++) {
        System.out.print(myArray[9][i]);
    }
```

Comment: Me ha quedado la primera parte clara y a partir de ahora mirare los caracteres que estoy convirtiendo ha sido muy útil y fructífera tu respuesta, me gustaría si es posible si me pudieses explicar la segunda parte, hay cosas que no entiendo, como por ejemplo el uso del Scanner con el fichero dentro, o también el segundo for, intuyo que utilizas el nextLine como si fuera un readLine de bufferRead y porque guardas los datos en un array de caracteres (chars), De nuevo quiero recalcar que tu respuesta ha sido muy pero que muy fructifera y ha saneado gran parte de mi codigo